# Drupal redirects again and again to the installation page after deploying to Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, drupal

I've made an Heroku app with latest Drupal 8.
After it, I've deployed it and configured the installation successfully.
Now I'm getting the problem where Drupal automatically redirects to the installation page when I open my application after 1-2 hours.
I feel that there's something to do with dynos.
And yes, I have a free account.

I've already tried searching a lot on google, but all the guides are outdated which are very complicated/do not make any sense.

The installation page of the Drupal should not come again and again. instead of it, the installation should be permanent.

Comment: I suspect Drupal's install process creates or modifies `settings.php` (and possibly other files), but those changes will not persist on Heroku due to the ephemeral filesystem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25218632/deploying-using-heroku See https://www.fomfus.com/articles/how-to-create-a-drupal-8-project-for-heroku-part-1 for a tutorial on working around this.

Answer (score 0):

If drupal is showing you install page that means that it didn't find the (old) database.

So either your database account data is not correct for new environment so it can't connect to database server ( sites/default/settings.php ) or something is wrong with your database (wiped out by heroku?). Check on database (with PHP MyAdmin or some similar tool maybe) to see do you have tables and data inside them.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has an ephemeral filesystem and Drupal creates/modifies some files during installation such as: "settings.php".
ephemeral file system means that all the modifications to the files/file system will be lost upon the dynos restarting.
So, as soon as Dynos do restart, the files are revert back to their original state.
Due to this, all the changes are wiped up and thus when you open the site/application, the drupal can't detect the installation and thats why it redirects to the installation page.
It all happens because the file changes do not persist if the file system is an ephemeral one.
as @ceejayoz suggested, please see this article for a possible work around by which you can fix this problem:
https://www.fomfus.com/articles/how-to-create-a-drupal-8-project-for-heroku-part-1